# Upgrade to 5.47.0 fails on my site with extensive use of CiviGrants

Tags: upgrade, civigrant

This is a D7 site. It uses CiviGrants and has over 600 of them using lots of custom fields. I am trying to upgrade from 5.46.2 to 5.47.0. When I run the db upgrade using the update url, it freezes right at the end. If I try to run the updates via Drush, I get the error:

> WD php: Error: Class 'CRM_Grant_DAO_Grant' not found in
> CRM_Core_PseudoConstant::get() (line 212 of           [error]
> /var/www/dev/web/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/PseudoConstant.php).
> Error: Class 'CRM_Grant_DAO_Grant' not found in
> CRM_Core_PseudoConstant::get() (line 212 of
> /var/www/dev/web/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/PseudoConstant.php).
> Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.

Comment: CiviGrant was moved to an extension in CiviCRM 5.47.  There was a lot of testing to avoid this sort of issue but it looks like you found an issue.  I would go to https://chat.civicrm.org, enter the `~product-maintenance` channel, and point them to this question.  This will get taken pretty seriously.

Comment: Daniel -> do you have any webform civicrm and/or civicrm entity integration?

Comment: @KarinG-SemperIT Yes, I have both Civi-Webform and Civi-Entity. I was thinking I should test the upgrade with them disabled.

Comment: @JonG-MegaphoneTech Thanks for the advice. I will post this on chat.civicrm.org

Comment: For Webform CiviCRM module (my team maintains that) -> download and install https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_civicrm/releases/7.x-5.8 [it's 5.47 compatible].

Comment: For CiviCRM Entity -> the maintainers have not issued a release yet. Ah I see you found Mattermost. See you there!

Answer (score 2):

Can you try to apply the [patch](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-drupal/pull/653/files)

Comment: Yay! That did bring back my CiviGrant Views. I applied it on a site that had already been updated so I did not test to see if the upgrade worked without crashing. I'll try that later or tomorrow. Thanks to so many people for working on this!